# Refactoring if-else block to use Map.computeIfAbsent Map.computeIfPresent wrong result

Tags: java

I have a class

```
public class Gezana {
    private String name;
    private long value;
}
```

and a list like:

```
List<Gezana> list = List.of(new Gezana("foo", 2), 
                            new Gezana("foo", 2),
                            new Gezana("foo", 2),
                            new Gezana("foo", 2), 
                            new Gezana("bar", 5),
                            new Gezana("bar", 5), 
                            new Gezana("bar", 5), 
                            new Gezana("doo", 9), 
                            new Gezana("doo", 9),
                            new Gezana("kee", 12));
```

I need to create a map using above list with name as key and sum of values as value. I used to do it in the following way:

```
Map<String, Long> oldMap = new HashMap<>(); 
for (Gezana gez : list) {            
    if (oldMap.containsKey(gez.getName())) {
        oldMap.put(gez.getName(), oldMap.get(gez.getName()) + gez.getValue());
    } else{
        oldMap.put(gez.getName(), gez.getValue());
    }          
}        
System.out.println("old map:" + oldMap);
```

I need to refactor the above and thought to use `Map.computeIfAbsent & Map.computeIfPresent` but getting not the expected result

```
Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>(); 
for (Gezana gez : list) {            
    map.computeIfAbsent(gez.getName(), k -> gez.getValue());     
    map.computeIfPresent(gez.getName(), (k, v)->  v + gez.getValue());              
}
System.out.println("new map:" + map);
```

Output:

```
old map:{bar=15, doo=18, foo=8, kee=12}
new map:{bar=20, doo=27, foo=10, kee=24}
```

It seems that the new map has one additional value for each key added, but i don't see the mistake in using the computeIfAbsent & computeIfPresent methods. Any hints?

Comment: I think you want `oldMap.merge(gez.getName(), gez.getValue(), Long::sum);`.

Comment: The problem with this is that `computeIfAbsent` always adds to the map; `computeIfPresent` will then update the thing that `computeIfAbsent` maybe just added.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you for the quick response. But the value is long not a string.

Comment: What do you think happens in `computeIfPresent()` after you've added the element in `computeIfAbsent()`? Note that `computeIfAbsent()` _adds_ the element to the map if it didn't exist yet so the first element for each key will be added twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with this is that `computeIfAbsent` always adds to the map; `computeIfPresent` will then update the thing that `computeIfAbsent` maybe just added.

So, when a name is first encountered, its value is added twice - once by the `computeIfAbsent`, then by the `computeIfPresent`.

You could do it with `computeIfAbsent/computeIfPresent` like this:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(gez.getName(), k -> 0L);     
map.computeIfPresent(gez.getName(), (k, v)->  v + gez.getValue());
```

or `compute`:

```
map.compute(gez.getName(), (k, v) -> (v != null ? v : 0L) + get.getValue());
```

but it would be easier with merge:

```
oldMap.merge(gez.getName(), gez.getValue(), Long::sum);
```

Or, directly from the list:

```
Map<String, Long> map = 
    list.stream().collect(groupingBy(Gezana::getName, summingLong(Gezana::getValue)))
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to apply `Map::merge` function:

```java
 Map<String, Long> oldMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Gezana gez : list) {
    oldMap.merge(gez.getName(), gez.getValue(), Long::sum);
}

System.out.println("old map:" + oldMap);
```

or use Stream API `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.summingLong`:

```java
Map<String, Long> newMap = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Gezana::getName, 
            Collectors.summingLong(Gezana::getValue)
        ));
System.out.println("new map:" + newMap);
```

Output:

```
old map:{bar=15, doo=18, foo=8, kee=12}
new map:{bar=15, doo=18, foo=8, kee=12}
```

Comment: In deed, merge seems to be the better alternative here. Thank you